# Convert matrix values in vector with some conditions

Tags: r, matrix, vector, dplyr

I'd like to convert matrix values in vector with some conditions. In my example:

```
# Create my matrix
mymatrix <-matrix(
    
  # Create a numeric variable 
  abs(rnorm(300)),
    
  # No of rows
  nrow = 10,   
    
  # No of columns
  ncol = 3,         
    
  # By default matrices are in column-wise order
  # So this parameter decides how to arrange the matrix
  byrow = TRUE          
)
# Naming rows
rownames(mymatrix) = 1:10
   
# Naming columns
colnames(mymatrix ) = c("1", "2", "3")

mymatrix
#            1          2           3
#1  0.85882558 1.38755611 0.369197570
#2  1.58785948 1.13064411 1.542977629
#3  0.35293056 1.44036121 1.806414543
#4  0.02709663 1.25620400 0.794001157
#5  0.34426152 0.32365824 2.026024465
#6  0.03608507 1.12315562 1.072635275
#7  0.39055300 0.49463748 0.645037388
#8  0.33406392 0.63543332 0.005055208
#9  1.04796081 0.04062249 2.330948193
#10 0.42538451 0.24574490 0.268357588
```

I'd like to convert my matrix to vector (`myvector`) using a custom rule:
If `mymatrix[,1]`is the maximum value in the row and `mymatrix[,1]>=0.95` then the vector result is "1", but if `mymatrix[,1]<0.95` than the result is "misclassified", but for `mymatrix[,2]` and `mymatrix[,3]` the result ("2") or ("3") is the maximum value inside each row. My desirable output is:

```
myvector
#[1] "2" "1" "3" "2" "3" "2" "3" "2" "1" "misclassified"
```

Please, any ideas?

Comment: `mymatrix[,1]` is not a value, but the whole column. What did you actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorised option -

```
#Get the column number of max value in each row
res <- max.col(mymatrix)
#Get row number where column 1 is highest
inds <- which(res == 1)
#If those value is less than 0.95 make it 'misclassified'
res[inds][mymatrix[inds, 1] < 0.95] <- 'misclassified'
res

#[1] "2"        "1"             "3"             "2"             "3"            
#[6] "2"        "3"             "2"             "3"             "misclassified"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to apply a function over your rows. So `apply` would be appropriate here:

```
apply(mymatrix, 1, \(x) { y <- which.max(x) 
if (y == 1) {if (x[y] >= 0.95) "1" else "misclassified"} else as.character(y)})
 [1] "2"             "1"             "3"             "2"             "3"            
 [6] "2"             "3"             "2"             "3"             "misclassified"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `apply` + `ifelse`

```
apply(
  mymatrix,
  1,
  function(x) {
    ifelse(max(x) >= 0.95,
      colnames(mymatrix)[which.max(x)],
      "misclassified"
    )
  }
)
```